PowerShell module ImportExcel could not be loaded, EPPlus.dll or dependencies not found
I'm trying to import Excel into my SQL Database via PowerShell. This script worked last week without any issues, but since today it gives me an error that it cannot run the Import-Excel command since it wasn't found in module ImportExcel. When I try to load the script it says the following:

I tried manually downloading EPPlus.dll for net462 and placed it in the folder. But it returns the same error, it cannot find the EPPlus.dll.

This is the script (anonimised):
# Install required modules
Install-Module -Name ImportExcel -Scope CurrentUser -Force -AllowClobber
Install-Module -Name SqlServer -Scope CurrentUser -Force -AllowClobber

# Parameters
$serverInstance = "XXX.database.windows.net"
$database = "XXX"
$username = "XXX"
$password = "XXX"
$excelPath = "C:\Users\XXX\Downloads\YM\YM_PrivAll.xlsx"

# Create connection string
$connectionString = "Server=$serverInstance; Database=$database; User ID=$username; Password=$password;"

# Import data from Excel
$excelData = Import-Excel -Path $excelPath

# Function to insert data
function Insert-Data {
    param($data)
    foreach ($row in $data) {
        $query = "INSERT INTO YM_PrivAll (FunctieID, Functie, BevoegdheidsID, Bevoegdheid, [Context \ resource], Licentie) VALUES ('$($row.FunctieID)', '$($row.Functie)', '$($row.BevoegdheidsID)', '$($row.Bevoegdheid)', '$($row.'Context \ resource')', '$($row.Licentie)')"
        Invoke-Sqlcmd -ConnectionString $connectionString -Query $query
    }
}

# Execute the function
Insert-Data -data $excelData

Do I miss anything obvious here?

I had a similar issue, code working fine in VSC but. Starting my script with Powershell.exe gave me this error. However changeing to pwsh.exe worked fine. Different versions of powershell appears to  be invoked.

I also have this if statement : if (-not (Get-Module -Name ImportExcel -ListAvailable)) {
Install-Module -Name ImportExcel -Scope CurrentUser -Force
}Import-Module ImportExcel

Installing an older module solved the problem. I saw there were changes during last week, so for now I stick to an older module. Thanks!
Install-Module -Name ImportExcel -RequiredVersion 7.1.0 -Scope CurrentUser -AllowClobber -Force


Which ImportExcel version were you using? 7.8.7 was released yesterday. 7.8.8 was released today.
